# When I pass ArrayList to ProcessBuilder I get the No such file or directory error

Tags: java

I have the following test code:

```
public class TestProcessBuilder {

public static void main(String args[]) {
String imageLocation = "/home/john/image";
String installCommand = "java -jar install.jar -install /home/john/install.properties";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

pb.directory(new File(imageLocation));
pb.command(Arrays.asList(installCommand.split("\\+s")));
  try {
      pb.start();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to run command");

  }

}
```

This gives me an error:

```
Cannot run program "java -jar install.jar -install /home/john/install.properties" (in directory "/home/john/"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Do I have to create a separate list and then manually add each tokenized item to it. I thought this should work...

Comment: I have also tried: `List<String>  list2 = new ArrayList<String> ();

for(String s: Arrays.asList(installCommand.split("\\+s"))) {
  list2.add(s);
}


pb.command(list2);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that path to your java folder is exported. You can then use something similar to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command = "java";
    String parameters = "-jar install.jar -install /home/john/install.properties";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command, parameters);

    try {
        pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Depends of your need, but you could use also this if you want to pass whole command in one string:

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar install.jar -install /home/john/install.properties");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried putting the java path in front of the command: `/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_75//bin/java -jar ...` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` is the only option that works. If I use the `command` and `parameters` option it tries to do this: `java "-jar install.jar -install /home/john/install.properties"` It puts double quotes around the parameters. If I convert the whole command + parameters to a list , I get `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -jar installer.jar -install /home/john/install.properties": error=2, No such file or directory` Maddeningly though, it doesn't say which of the files it cannot find!